# css :after overriding existing styles

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stylesheet

I am using asp.net mvc application to show a required symbol * and also a help symbol ? as characters. But the ? is overriding the * and I can finally see only one ? symbol. How can I show both the synmbols?

PS: I am trying to use 2 icons instead of text in this context. I am checking if we have an option to accommodate the icons instead of text.

Asp.Net MVC Code to show a label

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.myDetails, new { @class = "required labelHelp" })
```

Css Code to display * and ? after label

```
.required:after
{
    content: "*";
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}

.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "?";
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: it is normal. because second `:after` override first one.

Comment: Do we have any option to show both one next to another?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can have a css selector that check if an element have both classes apply `content: "* ?"`

```
.required:after
{
    content: "*";
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}

.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "?";
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #f00;
}

.required.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "* ?";
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

If you want an Icon to display:

```
.required:after
{
    content: "";
    background-image: url(/images/required.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}

.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "";
    background-image: url(/images/labelHelp.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}

.required.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "";
    background-image: url(/images/required_labelHelp.png);
    /* required_labelHelp.png should be an image that contains both required and labelHelp png*/
    width: 32px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: What if I a have to use icon for ? like
.required.labelHelp:after
{
    content: url('../Content/Images/icoHelp.png');
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #f00;
}

Comment: @Chandana I change the answer, I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7):

If you only have 2 possible icons, my suggestion would be to use both `:before` and `:after`. Since these pseudo-elements can only be used once per element (without overriding each other), this gives you the flexibility of having the 2 pseudo-elements applied at the same time, where each can have its own independent styles. You might need to add a little bit of additional CSS to correctly position the icons, but that should be straightforward.  Note this would not work if you need to apply 3+ icons since there are only 2 pseudo-elements, `:before` & `:after`.

```
.required:after
{
    content: "*";
    background-image: url(/images/required.png);
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}

.labelHelp:before
{
    content: "?";
    background-image: url(/images/labelHelp.png);
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Mohamad answer, a way to include the icons without need to create the composite image

```css
.required.labelHelp:after {
  content: "";
  background-image:
    url(http://placekitten.com/g/64/64),
    url(http://placekitten.com/g/64/60);
  background-position:
    left top,
    right top;
  background-size:
    60px
    60px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<label class="required labelHelp">text</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about strategically overriding the `:after`? You could do this by adding this CSS.

```
.required.labelHelp:after
{
    content: "* ?";
    padding-left: 3px;
    color: #f00;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p8u1zmhe/1/)**